# java.io.EOFException in ObjectInputStream while deserializing String

Tags: java, serialization, base64

I am getting an exception block

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3092)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2892)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1344)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
```

This error I am getting while deserializing a String object.
Serialization Code:

```
public <T> String serialize(T object) throws SerializationException
    {
        try {
            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
            objectOutputStream.flush();
            objectOutputStream.close();
            String serializedString =
                new String(base64.encode(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            return serializedString;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException(SERIALIZATION_FAILURE, e);
        }
    }
```

Deserialization Code

```
public <T> T deserialize(String string, Class<T> classType)
        throws SerializationException
    {
        try {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(string)) {
                return null;
            }

            byte[] bytesOfString = base64.decode(string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesOfString);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
            T deserializedObject = (T) objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
            return deserializedObject;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException(SERIALIZATION_FAILURE, e);
        }
```

When I am deserializing any pojo with CLASSNAME.class it is happening correctly but when I am trying to deserialize a String class with classtype String.class it is throwing this exception.

Comment: What exact base64 decoder/encoder used? With java.utils.Base64 it works w/o error

Comment: I think the problem is with the `base64.encode(...)` and `base64.decode(...)` methods. I've just tried your code by replacing those methods with `DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(...)` and `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(...)` and it works.